# Obtener columna DATE del JTable para guardarlo en SQL

Tags: java, sql, date

Tengo:

- SQL Server 2017
- Tengo `jcalendar-1.4` agregado a mi proyecto
- Tengo `import java.sql.Date;` en mi clase.
- Tengo la columna `fechaNacimiento` tipo `DATE` en mi base de datos.

Para obtener la información de la base de datos y armar el `model` del `JTable` uso:

```
String [] titulosColumnas = {"ID", "Nombre", "FechaNacimiento"};
            ArrayList<Object[]> registros = new ArrayList<Object[]>();

            while (rs.next()) {
                registros.add(new Object[] {
                    rs.getInt("id_director"),
                    rs.getString("nombre"),
                    // Aquí paso la información obtenida a String, porque JTable solo permite String's, cierto?.
                    rs.getDate("fechaNacimiento").toString()
                });
            }

            model = new DefaultTableModel(registros.toArray(new Object[0][]), titulosColumnas);
```

Mi JTable resultante:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En este momento, cuando hago clic en una fila del JTable, recibo el error:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   java.util.Date cannot be cast to java.sql.Date    at
>   vistas.Vista_director$7.mouseClicked(Vista_director.java:272)

Código del JTable cuando haces clic:

```
table = new JTable();
        scrollPane.setViewportView(table);
        table.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent arg0) {
                int fila = table.rowAtPoint(arg0.getPoint());
                datoDirector.setId(Integer.parseInt(table.getValueAt(fila, 0).toString()));
                datoDirector.setNombre(table.getValueAt(fila, 1).toString());
                // Obtener la columna Fecha Nacimiento
                Date date;
                try {
                    date = (Date) new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse((String)table.getValueAt(fila, 2));
                    datoDirector.setFechaNacimiento(date);
                } catch (ParseException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

Deseo obtener la fecha siendo tipo `DATE` para guardarla en una variable local tipo `DATE` también (la colocaré en un JDateChooser con su función .set()).

1. Cuál es la forma correcta para obtener el String que tiene el JTable y pasarlo a tipo DATE?
2. El uso de `rs.getDate("fechaNacimiento").toString()` es correcto o
   puedo eliminarle el `.toString()`?

Comment: en mi experiencia manejando fechas con JAVA siempre utilizo el paquete java.util.Date, y segun leo error que lanza durante la ejecución no logra transformar un objeto de tipo java.sql.Date a un java.util.Date, mi recomendacion para que realices la prueba, no importes el paquete java.sql.date. importa el java.util.date. me cuentas como te va!

Comment: @JosuéMartínez El error sigue. Alguna otra idea?, la forma en que estoy convirtiendo las cosas esta bien?.

Answer (score 0):

```
date = (Date) new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse((String)table.getValueAt(fila, 2));
```

el error debe existir en esta linea, haz ese procedimiento en varias lineas y prueba.

o en vez de usar el .parse(), utiliza el .format() de la clase SimpleDateFormat, y haces referencia a la celda de la tabla como lo haces actualmente.

```
date = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(table.getValueAt(fila, 2));
```

de esta forma, intentalo y escribes como te fue.